# Git switch branch in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have two branches (develop / master)

[image]

I want to switch branch in Eclipse but Master does not appear to select

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to fetch master from remote. Have you tried git fetch master?.

Comment: I've tried. Curious: fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: u need to specify remote url... try this  git fetch origin master .

Comment: It works,  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD, but in eclipse I still see the development BRANCH

Comment: now ... use git checkout -b master origin/master

Comment: fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'master' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/master' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108413/discussion-between-abhi-arora-and-nunito-de-la-calzada).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because you don't have a local master. If it is scenario, these steps might help you.

To fetch master, you simply need to:

```
git fetch origin master
```

This will fetch master for you. You can see the branches available for checkout with:

```
git branch -v -a
```

With the remote branches in hand, you now need to check out the branch you are interested in, giving you a local working copy:

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

Comment: I've got a fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'master' at the same time. Did you intend to checkout 'origin/master' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: can you show me the command which you have executed.
does it have any typo error?

Comment: attached as an image

Comment: You need to create a local branch that tracks a remote branch. The following command will create a local branch named master, tracking the remote branch origin/master. 

For earlier versions of git:

git checkout --track origin/master
For git 1.5.6.5 and higher:

git checkout --track -b origin/master

Answer (score 2):

In Git Repositories tab, after clone a repository, you should click it with right button -> "Fetch from origin" -> Configure -> Add -> type wanted branch -> Save and Fetch.